# Proof verification for proof by Karamata

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, contest-math, karamata-inequality

I was solving the following problem:
$$n^{a_1}+n^{a_2}+...+n^{a_{n+1}}\geq n^{a_1^{\frac{1}{n}}}+n^{a_2^{\frac{1}{n}}}+...+n^{a_{n+1}^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$
Where $n$ was meant to be natural, the $a_i$ positive and the constraint $\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}a_k=1$ was given. Let $a_i\geq a_j\iff i \geq j$.

If $n=1$, the problem statement is trivial, so let $n\geq 1$.
The way I now attempted to solve this was using the function $f(t)=e^{\ln(n)e^t}$. By manual verification, this function is convex on $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $t_i=\ln(a_i)$ Then the problem's constraint becomes:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n t_i=0$$

The problem now becomes:
$$f(t_1)+f(t_2)+ \dots +f(t_{n+1})\geq f\left( \frac{t_1}{n} \right) + f\left( \frac{t_2}{n} \right) + \dots + f\left( \frac{t_{n+1}}{n} \right)$$
But by construction, the $t_i$ majorize the $\frac{t_i}{n}$, so by Karamata, the inequality holds. Is this proof correct?

Either way, I would be very curious to see a non-analytic proof.

Comment: Could you fix your sub/superscripts, I'm pretty sure they're not correct at the moment

Comment: I think Karamata works. Assume that $t_1 \ge t_2 \ge \cdots \ge t_{n+1}$. Since $t_1 + t_2 + \cdots + t_{n+1} = 0$, we have $t_1 + t_2 + \cdots + t_k \ge 0$ for $k=1, 2, \cdots, n$. Thus, $t_1 + t_2 + \cdots + t_k \ge t_1/n + t_2/n + \cdots + t_k/n$ for $k = 1, 2, \cdots, n$. Thus, $(t_1, t_2, \cdots, t_{n+1})$ majorizes $(t_1/n, t_2/n, \cdots, t_{n+1}/n)$.

Comment: My reasoning exactly. I found the proof so non-involved however that I was sure I had messed up. Thanks a lot for the verification, however.

Comment: Is there an elegant= non- Karamata proof as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Without Karamata*:

By Bernoulli, we have
$a_1^{1/n} \le 1 + (a_1 - 1)/n$.
It suffices to prove that
$$n^{a_1} + \cdots + n^{a_{n+1}}
\ge n^{1 + (a_1 - 1)/n}
+ \cdots + n^{1 + (a_{n+1} - 1)/n}$$
or
$$n^{a_1-1} + \cdots + n^{a_{n+1} - 1} \ge n^{(a_1 - 1)/n} + \cdots + n^{(a_{n+1} - 1)/n}$$
or
$$b_1^n + b_2^n + \cdots + b_{n+1}^n
\ge b_1 + b_2 + \cdots + b_{n+1}$$
where $b_k = n^{(a_k - 1)/n}, ~ k=1, \cdots, n+1$.

By Bernoulli, we have $b_1^n \ge 1 + (b_1 - 1)n$. It suffices to prove that
$$(n+1) + (b_1 + \cdots + b_{n+1} - (n+1))n \ge b_1 + \cdots + b_{n+1}$$
or
$$b_1 + \cdots + b_{n+ 1} \ge n + 1$$
which is true, using
$$b_1 b_2 \cdots b_{n+1}
= n^{(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{n+1} - (n+1))/n} \ge 1.$$

We are done.

Comment: Repeated Bernoulli and AM-GM. Elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

Show for $x>0$,$n\geq 3$ that there is positive constant such that :

$$n^{x}-n^{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}-C\ln\left(x\right)\geq 0$$

Summing yields the inequality .